# Grub2 - Failure with UUID

Tags: grub2

Trying to use `UUID` or `PARTUUID` but these partitions are never found when I use them. They do work if I use the oldschool way of hd(), sdc3, etc. But I would rather use the UUID way. I've tried both the UUID and PARTUUID to no success.

```
menuentry "Gentoo uuid" --class gentoo --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    insmod ext2
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root UUID=00021db0-01
    echo    OTHER  system...
    linux   /kernel1 root=UUID=0 021db0-03 rootfstype=ext4 log_buf_len=512K video=uvesafb:mtrr:3,ywrap,1024x768-32  
}
```

---

```
localhost four # blkid
/dev/sdc1: UUID="fb3da30a-f151-4252-818c-5b60d17a6951" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="00021db0-01" 
/dev/sdc3: UUID="5be3a16f-029f-431b-868d-eeb0aa451591" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="00021db0-03"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Arch Linux with UUID identification for partitions.

Try something like the below,
which is slightly different syntax then what you have.

`search --no-floppy --fs-uuid  --set=root 3ac46797-f613-4d58-9dec-b2eebfe4cf08`

`linux /kernel1 root=UUID=3ac46797-f613-4d58-9dec-b2eebfe4cf08 rootfstype=ext4 log_buf_len=512K video=uvesafb:mtrr:3,ywrap,1024x768-32`